# Downloading resource files in Android

Tags: android, file, background, download

I've been trying to make a game, and I'm getting the background music to work right now. The files are simply too large to fit in the res/raw directory and compile into an apk, so I'm  downloading them from online. This is a good solution; it doesn't use up any space on the phone and it plays smoothly, just that it won't work if the phone can't connect to the internet when the app is running. A better solution would be to download the music when the app starts for the first time, but I can't find the documentation on how to do this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > A better solution would be to download the music when the app starts for the first time, but I can't find the documentation on how to do this.

There are lots of documentation of how to download a file. So, if you want to know when the app starts the first time you can do it using SharedPreferences ([here is an example](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)).

Also, you can check if the files are there before trying to download them:

```
File theFile = new File("/sdcard/blah");
if(!theFile.exists(){
    // if it does not exists it means that it has not been downloaded
    // or maybe the user delete it
}
```

Comment: pipped to the post there, i 2nd this as its exactly the same answer i was just about to post. +1

Comment: I managed to find a tutorial for downloading files here: http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-download-fileimage-url-your-device . Thanks for the help with the file IO.